# Can you define a manual order of columns via PROC FREQ?

Tags: sas, bar-chart

I am new to SAS but I am preparing a lecture explaining some basic SAS.
I want to show how you can create a bar chart with SAS (version 9.4).
For this purpose, I use the "heart" example data set in SAS.

If I create a bar chart via `PROC FREQ` for the variable "Smoking_Status", I get an ordering of the bars that is not useful.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.heart;
  tables Smoking_Status / plots = freqplot;
run;
```

[image: Bar chart via FREQ]

Is it possible to order the bars manually in `PROC FREQ`, maybe via the `ORDER=` argument? I could not see how. I want the graph to have nice descriptions and not prefix the labels with "1-" or "2-" to be able to order them alphabetically because that reduces the readability of the resulting plot.

I can achieve the desired result with `SGPLOT`.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.heart;
  vbar Smoking_Status;  
  title "Distribution of smoking_status from sashelp.heart dataset";
  xaxis display=(nolabel) values=('Non-smoker' 'Light (1-5)' 'Moderate (6-15)' 
    'Heavy (16-25)' 'Very Heavy (> 25)');
run;
```

[image: Bar chart via SGPLOT]

My question is: Is there also a way to achieve this result via `PROC FREQ`?
I want to be sure whether this is the case or not because I want to show the easiest and most straightforward solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via the `ORDER=` statement. The default is `INTERNAL`, which works on unformatted values and puts character variables alphabetically. It's often more flexible to convert your grouping variable to numeric, and apply a format that sets the desired label. Alternatively you could use `ORDER=DATA` and add records in the correct order at the top of your dataset with zero weight for example.

Example SAS code for both approaches (you only need to do one):

```
/* Formats for option 1, can also generate these from the data. */
proc format;
   invalue smoke_num
      "Non-smoker" = 1
      "Light (1-5)" = 2
      "Moderate (6-15)" = 3
      "Heavy (16-25)" = 4
      "Very Heavy (> 25)" = 5;

   value smoke_label
      1 = "Non-smoker"
      2 = "Light (1-5)"
      3 = "Moderate (6-15)"
      4 = "Heavy (16-25)"
      5 = "Very Heavy (> 25)";
run;



data want;
   /* Option 2: add dummy records with zero weight for ORDER=DATA. */
   length Smoking_Status $17;
   if _N_ eq 1 then do;
      wt = 0;
      do smoking_status = "Non-smoker",
                          "Light (1-5)",
                          "Moderate (6-15)",
                          "Heavy (16-25)",
                          "Very Heavy (> 25)";
         output;
      end;
   end;
   wt = 1;

   set sashelp.heart;
   /* Option 1: set order through formatted numeric variable. */
   smokeN = input(smoking_status, smoke_num.);
   format smokeN smoke_label.;

   output; /* Needed for option 2 (implicit output is gone). */
run;

/* Option 1. */
proc freq data=want order=internal;
   tables smoken / plots=freqplot;
   format smoken smoke_label.; /* Already applied above as well. */
   weight wt; /* Only needed to exclude dummy records if they are present. */
run;


/* Option 2. */
proc freq data=want order=data;
   tables smoking_status / plots=freqplot;
   weight wt;
run;
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add SAS code to do those things and create the plot? Without this it is hard to judge how well that actually works.

Comment: Sure, your post didn't include any PROC FREQ code so I had nothing to go on, I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the PROC FREQ code that I had forgotten previously in my answer. I can now confidently tell the students that it is possible to achieve it also with PROC FREQ but the solution will be more involved than simply using SGPLOT.

Comment: I would recommend telling the students they can get it easily with PROC FREQ, if their data are coded appropriately.  Note that if SmokingStatus is coded 1=NonSmoker, 2=Light, etc, with an appropriate format attached, this not only makes the PROC FREQ code easy, it also makes the SGPLOT code easier, because you don't have to specify the x-axis values. A lot of learning SAS is learning how to store data.